Generalization of Heat input in a $pV$ curve for a reversible process
I was wondering, is there a way to generalize by just looking at a PV curve for a certain process that heat flows into it or out of?
For example, for a cyclic process if the process is "clockwise" then you could say heat has been supplied to the system. ( please do correct me if im wrong here )
Likewise for a non cyclic process, without spending a lot of time analyzing the process, can we state that it absorbs or rejects heat?
One factor I thought of was joining the initial coordinate to an adiabatic curve passing through that point and observing if the graph of our function lies above or below it, not sure if that's helpful but please do point it out in case of it being correct / incorrect.
Thank you

I don't think you can.  The adiabat and the isotherm have similar shapes.

@ChetMiller if im not wrong then for similar initial coordinates, the final pressure is lower in an adiabatic as compared to an isothermal for the same final volume

Yes, you are correct.

@ChetMiller , in the pv curve it is obvious that for any process lying above the isotherm it is accepting heat and for any process below the adiabat it is rejecting heat, for any curve lying between them is what im generalising, and i still think it should be + for it since for the adiabat the internal energy reduction perfectly balances the work done by the gas meanwhile for the same reduction there is a greater work done for process lying above the adiabat hence having a overall heat acceptance, hence any curve that is cut by an adiabat can be broken into parts and simplified like this

I don't follow your last sentence.  Also, look up polytropic process.

@ChetMiller im aware of polytropic processes, altho ive not come across this. my last sentence i meant to say is that, say we draw an adiabat from the intial cordinate, and some part P1 lies above the adiabat, then heat is absorbed into that system for that part, and likewise for some part P2 lying below it. i come through with this by the logic that i had seen a few years ago, point at which an adiabat touched the curve was point of 0 heat exchange, altho i have to admit im a bit hazy about this, if you could refer some source it would really help

What matters is the slope of the curve on a log-log plot.  From that, you can determine the polytropic index, which tells you immediately whether heat is being added or removed.

@ChetMiller could you give a brief about how the index of the polytropic determines if heat is released or absorber

@ChetMiller Don't all polytropic processes other than the  reversible adiabatic processes, involve heat?

Modt thermo books have this.


I was wondering, is there a way to generalize by just looking at a PV
curve for a certain process that heat flows into it or out of?

I'll assume you are asking about closed systems (no exchange of mass with the surroundings) of ideal gases. It can be difficult to determine if heat is involved if looking at a single process curve in isolation.
The exceptions are the isobaric (constant pressure) and isochoric (constant volume) processes where it can be shown, by combining the first law and ideal gas equation, that both involve heat addition or heat removal, depending on the direction of the process. The isochoric and isobaric processes are polytropic processes where the polytropic index is $n=\infty$ and $n=0$, respectively, in the figure below. (Note the figure assumes an ideal gas and only shows common examples of polytropic processes.)
For any other polytropic process in the figure below, heat is added or removed depending on the direction of the process, with the sole exception of the reversible adiabatic (isentropic) process where $Q=0$. The reversible adiabatic process is a polytropic process where the polytropic index, $n$, is the ratio of the specific heat at constant pressure to the specific heat at constant volume, in the figure below.
Hope this helps.


hi! thanks for the comment, if its possible could you expand more on the variation with polytropic exponent or cite some source so i can grasp this furthur. Not regarding this in particular, but you might have seen the variation of C ( molar heat capacity) with polytropic exponent, and you can see as it tends towards infinity, the C approaches a constant, that is it approaches the isochoric process, so can we say all process between the adiabat and the isochoric reject heat meanwhile all betwen the isobaric and isochoric accept it? thank you

@doge expand on the variation with polytropic component in what  way? Regarding  variation of C with polytropic index, you should post that question in a separate post.

sorry for the confusion, i meant variation of heat intake with the variation in adiabatic exponent, this is what i elaborated on furthur, that if the index is increased tending towards infinity, the C tends towards being equal to Cv, which is heat capacity at constant volume, and for that process the pV curve will appear to be a vertical line, so extrapolating your diagram, it will furthur become more steep until it becomes a straight vertical line passing through that point? please do correct me if im wrong

@doge you’re confusing the general polytropic index $n$ with the adiabatic index $\gamma$. The adiabatic index which is the ratio $C_{p}/C_{v}$ for ideal gases and where $C_{p}=C_{v}+R$, is a special case of the polytropic index with a narrow range of finite values

@doge You can calculate the polytropic index for any process from the following $$n= Log[P_{f}/P_{i}]/Log[V_{i}/V{f}]$$ That gives you $n=0$ for isobaric process, $n=\infty$ for isochoric process and n=1 for isothermal process.

@doge keep in mind the above equation assumes a reversible process involving an ideal gas

Ultimately it depends on the equation of state, but in general if work is extracted from a system in a closed loop, the work must be compensated with heat for the system to return to its initial energy.  For example, in an ideal gas (whose equation of state is $PV=Nk_BT$, and whose energy is given by $U\propto Nk_BT\propto PV$) if a loop progresses clockwise, then the system performs/expends more work on expanding than it receives on compression and so it must absorb energy during a cycle.
As for how heat is absorbed/emitted (or whether heat is absorbed/emitted in a non-cyclic process), that ultimately depends on the form of the level surfaces for energy and entropy. The most straightforward way to check if heat is absorbed or emitted that I'm aware of is basically the process you describe: if you know the adiabats and can easily determine the energy of a given point in state space (e.g. a particular $(p,V)$ value for a simple gas), then simply trace an adiabat from the final point on the curve to the initial configuration modulo energy and then check if the energy of the resulting point is higher or lower than that of the starting point of the curve.
